# Using the sum if function

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, formula

I have a sum if function and works well but I have to manually update the conditional statement.  This works well when there are only a few lines but in this particular sheet its almost 200 lines.  Does anybody know a way to tweak this formula.

Thanks

I've tried

```
=SUMIF($C$7:$C$56,"=$R15",$H$7:$H$56)
```

and

```
=SUMIF($C$7:$C$56,"=R15",$H$7:$H$56)
```

Column R is the information i'm updating manually.  When I type in a specific number the formual works but if I leave it as a column then it returns 0.

so if I did

```
=SUMIF($C$7:$C$56,"=21",$H$7:$H$56) This works
```

Comment: Try without the quotes. `=SUMIF($C$7:$C$56, $R15,$H$7:$H$56)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
=SUMIF($C$7:$C$56, $R15, $H$7:$H$56)
```

Comment: additionally this also worked : =SUMIF($C$7:$C$372,"="&R29,$H$7:$H$372)